# Google smart action

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-developer-tools

We develop an app to be used with Google assissant. All works fine in develop envirnoment, than when we deploy in test envirnoment on aws we have these errors from Google:
DEADLINE_EXCEDEED
RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
these when we answer to a Sync request.
The account link and the First Sync are working fine!
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` - This generally happens when an intent request times out waiting for a response. If you're seeing these errors during account linking, it may also be related to the time taken to issue the OAuth token in addition to the initial `SYNC`.

`RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` -  This happens when you call Request Sync more than once concurrently for a given `agentUserId`. For more details see the **Error responses** section of the Request Sync [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync).

Comment: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED It Is not happening in account linking but after a Sync triggered by a refresh in Google app. We check for a delay but we check in logs that our response arrives in less than 500 msec. RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED we Will check but Also this happens answering the Sync called by google